# SQL MIN with convert Function as Military time

Tags: sql

This Works Perfectly, but returns the latest time...

```
 CONVERT(nvarchar(10), dbo.UDO_VW_LocalPanelTime.DATE, 108) AS Q_Event_Time,
```

How do i get it for the First instance.  Right now it shows the Last Instance.  i believe a min function is needed...i could be wrong...Kinda new to SQL...Learning the ways of the force...

eg
11:52,
13:03,
15:15,
17:00

The Code above returns 17:00, I need it to return 11:52

Can anyone provide an updated code for this please?

Here is the Pre CODE:

```
CREATE VIEW UDO_VW_LocalPanelTime
AS
SELECT     dbo.EVENTS.EMPID, 

CASE WHEN (EVENT_TIME_UTC > DST_Start_CurrentYear AND EVENT_TIME_UTC < DST_End_CurrentYear) 
THEN 

DATEADD(MI,GMTOFFSET - DAYLIGHTBIAS, EVENT_TIME_UTC) ELSE DATEADD(MI, GMTOFFSET, EVENT_TIME_UTC) END AS DATE, 

dbo.EVENTS.MACHINE, 
dbo.EVENTS.CARDNUM, dbo.EVENTS.DEVID

FROM         dbo.EVENTS INNER JOIN
                      dbo.READER ON dbo.EVENTS.DEVID = dbo.READER.READERID AND dbo.EVENTS.MACHINE = dbo.READER.PANELID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UDO_WV_PanelPlusDST ON dbo.READER.PANELID = dbo.UDO_WV_PanelPlusDST.PANELID

GO
```

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You should be able to use the MIN() function...something like CONVERT(nvarchar(10), MIN(dbo.UDO_VW_LocalPanelTime.DATE, 108)) AS Q_Event_Time...It's hard to provide an entire query with so less information about your table structure and data.

Comment: here is what i did.....   MIN(CONVERT(nvarchar(10), dbo.UDO_VW_LocalPanelTime.DATE, 108)) AS Q_Event_Time,  Came back with...Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UDO_VW_ExportView, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
The MIN function requires 1 argument(s).   Then i did....MIN(dbo.UDO_VW_LocalPanelTime.DATE, 108) AS Q_Event_Time,  which errored to...Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UDO_VW_ExportView, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
The MIN function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: In the second code above...i have this line...could it be placed here?   SELECT     dbo.EVENTS.EMPID, 

CASE WHEN (EVENT_TIME_UTC > DST_Start_CurrentYear AND EVENT_TIME_UTC < DST_End_CurrentYear) 
THEN 

DATEADD(MI,GMTOFFSET - DAYLIGHTBIAS, EVENT_TIME_UTC) ELSE DATEADD(MI, GMTOFFSET, EVENT_TIME_UTC) END AS DATE,

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. I think the example in my comment was also incorrect syntax. Should be CONVERT(nvarchar(10), MIN(dbo.UDO_VW_LocalPanelTime.DATE), 108) AS Q_Event_Time. But as already said, I can't providing a complete query without knowing your tables and their contents.